# How ROS/openni convert kinect's raw disparity to depth(millimeter unit)?

Tags: ros, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Formula(including the default parameter value) please!!

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41423/how-ros/openni-convert-kinect%27s-raw-disparity-to-depth(millimeter-unit)?/) by [ranqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2941/ranqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps this link can help you
http://blog.mivia.dk/2011/06/my-kinect-datasheet/

---

Originally posted by [DiogoCorrea](https://answers.ros.org/users/933/diogocorrea/) with karma: 61 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0